# stan - 2 approaches to missing value imputation; which is better and why?

Tags: data-imputation, stan, rstan

So, me and a colleague have to impute some data, x, given a categorical variable. We arrived at two different approaches:

a) as in the tutorial: split x into x_obs and x_mis, and treat x_mis as parameters. Something like this:

```
data {
  int<lower=0> N_obs;
  int<lower=0> N_mis;
  int J; // number of package types
  real<lower = 0.01> x_obs[N_obs];
  int<lower = 1, upper = J> ptype_obs[N_obs];
  int<lower = 1, upper = J> ptype_mis[N_mis];
}
parameters {
  real<lower = 0.01> x_mis[N_mis];
  matrix<lower = 0.01>[J] mu_x;
  matrix<lower = 0.01, upper=5>[J] sigma_x;
}

transformed parameters {
  vector<lower = 0.01>[N_obs] x_obs_mu;
  vector<lower = 0.01>[N_obs] x_obs_sigma;
  vector<lower = 0.01>[N_mis] x_mis_mu;
  vector<lower = 0.01>[N_mis] x_mis_sigma;

  for(i in 1:N_obs){
    x_obs_mu[i]=mu_x[ptype_obs[i]];
    x_obs_sigma[i]=sigma_x[ptype_obs[i]];
  }
  for(i in 1:N_mis){
    x_mis_mu[i]=mu_x[ptype_mis[i]];
    x_mis_sigma[i]=sigma_x[ptype_mis[i]];
  }
}

model {
  x_obs ~ normal(x_obs_mu,x_obs_sigma);
  x_mis ~ normal(x_mis_mu,x_mis_sigma);
}
```

b) saying "There is some real value, x_real, and both x_obs and x_mis tend around it. Here is sample code:

```
data {
  int N;
  int J;
  real x[N];
  real volume[N];
  int<lower = 0, upper = 1> x_available[N];
  int<lower = 1, upper = J> ptype[N];
}
parameters {
  vector<lower = 0>[N] x_real;
  vector<lower = 0.1>[J] mu_x_package;
  vector<lower = 0.0>[J] sigma_x_package;
}

transformed parameters {
  vector<lower = 0.01>[N] x_real_mu;
  vector<lower = 0.01>[N] x_real_mu1;
  vector<lower = 0.01>[N] x_real_sigma;
  vector<lower = 0.01>[N] x_real_sigma1;

  for(i in 1:N){

   if(x_available[i]==1){
      x_real_mu[i]=x[i];
      x_real_sigma[i]=0.1;
    }else{
     x_real_mu[i]=mu_x_package[ptype[i]];
     x_real_sigma[i]=sigma_x_package[ptype[i]];
    }
   x_real_mu1[i]=mu_x_package[ptype[i]];
   x_real_sigma1[i]=sigma_x_package[ptype[i]];
  }
}

model {
  mu_x_package~normal(1.2,0.4);
  sigma_x_package~normal(0.5,0.3);
  x_real~normal(x_real_mu,x_real_sigma);
  x_real_mu~normal(x_real_mu1,x_real_sigma1);
}
```

Now, approach b) is very inelegant in that there is x_real_mu and x_real_mu1, and ***both are necessary for some reason***, which I just can't understand why. If I remove either one, the model converges quickly, but produces nonsensical results.

On the other hand, approach a) is somewhat redundant in that I have to duplicate most of my work.

Which approach is better and why? Also, for b), why do we need both x_real_mu, and x_real_mu1 ?

Comment: You might get better answers if you *describe* the two imputation strategies in more detail: not everyone here will be able to read your code.

Comment: In the model a) it looks very unusual to me that the observed and missing values have separate sampling statements. In my understanding that is not what the Stan manual suggests.